# LineIterator.hasNext() throws exception if last line of the file is not empty

Tags: java, iterator, java-io

I have a piece of code that looks like this (in java) which uses org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.lineIterator;

```
LineIterator iterator = lineIterator(someFile, defaultCharset());
....
while(iterator.hasNext){
 process(iterator);
}

private String process(LineIterator iterator, SomeComplexClass someClass){
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
  //do something using iterator.nextLine()
 }
}
```

This works perfectly if my input file has an empty last row.

```
Input file:
Line1
Line2
(nothing here. just empty line)
```

But if I have my input file without an empty line, then lineIterator.hasNext() throws exception saying "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream already closed"

```
Input file:
Line1
Line2 //there is no empty line after this
```

Is this a known behaviour of LineIterator?
Please help me try to understand why is it happening like this.

Update: I don't see close() or LineIterator.closeQuietly(iterator) in the code. Can that cause the issue?

Comment: How did you get the `LineIterator`?

Comment: Please publish *all* the relevant code, how do you create `lineIterator`, how do you consume the tokens and etc.

Comment: I'm creating it like this LineIterator iterator = lineIterator(someFile, defaultCharset()).
I added it to the question too

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I looked at the code some more added few more details to the question. Is this happening because I'm passing iterator to another method?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: The function `process` mismatched the signature upon calling it. Is there an override method? Please include all the relevant code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file reading in text editor  which can show line numbers like notepad++
then if the last line is empty.Delete that last line.

Blank space does not mean there is no line

Answer (score -1):

If you look at LineIterator hasNext() [LineIterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.java#LineIterator),
it seems to have a bug.  To work, it should set cachedLine to null when it reaches the end of the file, but instead only sets a "finished" flag.  Unfortunately, at the start of the method, cachedLine is checked before the finished flag, so you get true even if the end of file is reached.